# Jquery Ajax - Get API call with dynamic pagination

Tags: jquery, ajax

I make a GET call using Ajax, it works well and has the expected result. But the API I use has a limit of 50, and uses pagination.
What I want to do is to get **all** data before I call `myFunction(data)`, so that I can send that function everything, currently I only get the first 50 objects.

```
$.ajax({
  url: "test.html",
  method: 'GET',
  cache: false,
  success: function(data){
    myFunction(data);
  }
});
```

It's easy to check if the GET has a next page, as it the return the url of the next page, otherwise it's empty.

Comment: Do you want to display all data on the webpage or would you prefer to stick to paged lists? It has two different approaches.

Comment: Ah good point, I want to display all data. Basically I just want a way to get all the data to `myFunction()`, which then draws a graph using that data.

Comment: Where is the API you are using? Is it in "test.html" or is it external? i.e. Does "test.html" make a call to the API or is "test.html" your API?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create recursive function and you can try this with ajax call async:false.

```
 var totalPagesLength = 5;
    var pagescount=0;
            function recursively_ajax() {
                $.ajax({
                    url: "test.html",
                    method: 'GET',
                    async:false,
                    cache: false,
                    success: function (data) {
                        pagescount++;
                        if (pagescount < totalPagesLength) {
                            recursively_ajax();
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
```

Comment: where is the call to myFunction(data); ? that was mentioned in the question.